# Link(s) to specific word search results?

Tags: search-results, hyperlink, keyword

I need to create a few links that will search for a predefined keyword search across my whole SP site. How do I do this?

Example: If I add a link called "Apple" to a page, when someone clicks on it I want it to go to a search results page that brings up all content (Announcements, list items, documents) related to Apple.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your search center and search for "Apple" and go to the results.aspx site. That should be your default search page.

The URL should look similar to this:

```
https://<YourSharePoint>/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=apple
```

Now you can create e.G. a Link-WebPart and create an item with that link, otherwise you can just add a Content Editor to your site and add under "Edit Source" an link.